# Spring Boot 2 | Very basic Dependency Injection @Autowired question

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Very new to Java Spring Boot 2. Apologies in advance for what I am sure is a seriously dumb question.

Background:
For me, I need to see and understand, first of all, a very pure and simple implementation of a concept before I can begin to extrapolate the utility of the concept or technique.

Therefore I am trying to set up an idiot-proof example showing @Autowired and DI 'at work' which I can fully understand before moving on.

I have tried to set up a super simple Spring Boot 2 project with just two classes; [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kkvo.jpg) "TesterApplication" which contains the psvm and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR0kA.jpg) 'Users' which is a very simple class which contains a single field 'name', with a no args constructor. See images:

The PSVM is here:

```
package com.tester.kryten.tester;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class TesterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("1. Pre Spring Run");
        SpringApplication.run(TesterApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("2. Post Spring Run");

        @Autowired
        Users user;
        System.out.println("3. " + user.getName());

    }
}
```

The 'Users' class is here:

```
package com.tester.kryten.tester;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Users {

    public String name = "foo bar";

    @Autowired
    public Users() {
            System.out.println("User class constructor called");
        }

    public String getName() { return name; }

}
```

Now, ALL I am trying to do is understand the correct way to reference and USE a Spring managed instance of 'User' in another class, in this simple example the TesterApplication class.

I am reading about how it's frowned upon to use:

```
Users user = new User();
```

And that its better to use Spring DI to manage dependencies, so how would it be done in this example?
What is throwing me is that on line 20 of the TesterApplication class I am getting the expected code completion from Intellij offering me the getName() method. This makes me think that the instance must me there, but I just get:

> Error:(17, 9) java: annotation type not applicable to this kind of
>   declaration

Could some kind soul out there please put me out of my misery and tell me where I'm misunderstanding how to simply inject an instance of Users into TestApplication.class - **the right way?** Please.

Comment: Please, post your code, no images.

Comment: Especially since you've made multiple mistakes!

Comment: @PeterMmm - Ok I've replaced the images with code.

Comment: @Robert Moskal - If I had not made mistakes do you think I'd be asking for help ;-)

Comment: You should know that a Spring bean usually follows the singleton pattern which means that the way you defined it, there will always only be one single instance of 'Users'. Also, the way you try to autowire it is not correct. I can't be autowired in a static context like you do. It should be a non-static field of a class.

Comment: i recommend that you go through a tutorial first like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start

Comment: Spring beans are usually _service_ objects, not _data_ objects (the main exception being `@ConfigurationProperties` for setting up the application at startup). Java doesn't have "struct" (everything is a class), but there's an important conceptual distinction between "classes that implement a process" and "classes that represent data".

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `User user;` outside of main method. It have to be class property, not local variable
2. You do not need `@Authowired` annotation for constructor in `Users` class
3. You can use `@Authovired` annotation for constructor if it is parametrised by other Spring beans to inject them

Comment: I would just one more note.  The static main method will not have access to an instance member like User. It won't even compile. So you need to find another way to test this.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I see what you mean, its a poor example. I'll maybe add an @Controller and test it by sending http requests.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is the use of the @Component annotation. When you put the annotation on a class as in your case Users during the start of the application context, the constructor of the Users class is invoked by creating a Users object and adding it to the Spring IOC container. To use this object inside another class just create an attribute of type Users and put the @Autowired annotation on this attribute not inside the method. So you can use this attribute in the methods of your class. Also, you don't need to put the @Autowired annotation on the Users class constructor.